Writing a generator to load data in chunks , use of .readline() to skip column name
def read_large_file(file_object):   # Define read_large_file()
    """A generator function to read a large file lazily."""

    file_object.readline() # Skip the header line

    # Loop indefinitely until the end of the file
    while True:
        # Read a line from the file: data
        data = file_object.readline()

        # Break if this is the end of the file
        if not data:
            break

        # Yield the line of data
        yield data
        
with open('world_dev_ind.csv') as file:          #Open a connection to the file
    # Create a generator object for the file: gen_file
    gen_file = read_large_file(file)

    # Print the first three lines of the file
    print(next(gen_file))
    print(next(gen_file))
    print(next(gen_file))

in the above code the line-
# Skip the header line
    file_object.readline()

Will it not omit one line from the data every time we apply next() on the generator function?

Can you explain the result you are looking for?  I don't understand what's wrong with the code you have.

A generator continues after the yield, not leaving the loop in your case.

file_object.readline() is not in the loop. It's only done once, when the generator first starts. So it only skips one header line.

Each time you call next() you get the next value that's yielded, and it continues inside the loop.

Are you sure the contents of your file are as expected? Can you give a small example CSV text, your expected output, and your actual/unexpected output?

note, you should just use next(file_object), file objects are iterators over the lines, "A generator function to read a large file lazily." is kind of pointless. file objects are already lazy iterators.

You can just skip the header, then iterate over the rest of the file object. don't use .readline!

Don't run through your CVS file line by line. Use the built-in cvs reader instead. See this answer post that shows the code you want here.
